# Field update on custom field based on the value of a standard field with different types?

Tags: field-update

I have a custom field(House Number) with type "text" and I want this field to be updated with the value of a standard field(Shipping street) with type "Address". How can this be done using Workflow Rules with criteria that a custom field (Partner Function) should not contain Value as "sh"?But its not working properly.Can anyone help me with this??

[image: Field Update]

[image: Workflow rule]

Comment: what's not working ? can you tell us how you tested this and what data you used for testing ?

Comment: Condition is-"Partner function"field should not be("sh").If criteria meets,  House number field should be updated with  the value of the standard field"Billing Address".

Comment: If you have the field update run on a non-address field, or even with a text string, does it work?  Maybe it's the rule, and not the update.  I'd also try switching the EvalCriteria to "every time it's edited" to verify the rule is working as expected.